# Improving efficiency of SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, performance

This is a theoretical example - a question I've been posed as a way of helping me learn. I'd appreciate any pointers and explanation, as when it comes to large scale databases, I am more than amateur but keen to learn more.

The following SQL is about to be run on a database of 8 million records, what can be done to improve efficiency?

```
SELECT
   email_subscribers_extra.sendscont,   
   email_list_subscribers_new.subscriberid,
   email_subscribers_extra.lastopen  
FROM 
   email_list_subscribers_new 
LEFT JOIN 
   email_subscribers_extra ON email_subscribers_extra.subscriberid = email_list_subscribers_new.subscriberid 
WHERE 
   email_list_subscribers_new.partner = 'AJ' 
ORDER BY 
   email_subscribers_extra.lastsend ASC LIMIT 0, 40000
```

EDIT:
Lets presume that it is a Linux apache, mysql server as that is what I typically use. There are no indexing set at present.

Comment: Well, for one: `LIMIT` is **not** part of any ANSI/ISO SQL standard... so you already are very specific in what database systems will even support this....

Comment: Are there any indexes on the tables in question?

Comment: EXPLAIN PLAN will tell you better than anyone here.

Comment: Is there a form of explain plan for phpmyadmin? I've never come across this before and it looks amazing.

Answer (score 2):

*Improving efficiency* is a loaded phrase in SQL tuning. You usually add indexes to speed up SELECT performance, but adding indexes usually slows down updates. Every INSERT and DELETE statement requires rewriting indexes. Many UPDATE statements will require rewriting indexes, too.

Without looking at the execution plan, and without considering the effect on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements, I'd suggest adding indexes on

- every column used in the WHERE clause,
- every column used in the JOIN condition,
- every column used in the ORDER BY.

Most dbms will automatically add an index to columns used in a foreign key reference. At least some of them will let you drop that index later, though.

So add an index, or make sure the index supporting a foreign key constraint exists, on these columns.

- email_list_subscribers_new.subscriberid
- email_list_subscribers_new.partner
- email_subscribers_extra.subscriberid
- email_subscribers_extra.lastsend

In some cases, one multi-column index will give you better SELECT performance than two single-column indexes.